# Ten Green Bottles - charAt error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, char

I am working on a Codewars challenge (here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/ten-green-bottles) that makes use of a `for` loop. I am still editing the code, however, no matter how much I change, it continues to say that there was an error with `charAt`. My code is here:

```js
function tenGreenBottles(n) {
  var numbers = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three",
  "Four",
  "Five",
  "Six",
  "Seven",
  "Eight",
  "Nine",
  "Ten"
  ];
  var lyrics = "";
  for (i = n - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    var numberLine = numbers[i] + " green bottles hanging on the wall,\n";
    var nextNumber = numbers[i - 1].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + numbers[i - 1].slice(1, numbers[i - 1].length);
    if (i < 9) {
      lyrics = lyrics + numberLine + numberLine + "And if one green bottle should accidentally fall,\n" + "There'll be " + nextNumber + " green bottles hanging on the wall.\n";
    }
    else {
      lyrics = lyrics + "One green bottle hanging on the wall,\n" + "One green bottle hanging on the wall,\n" + "If that one green bottle should accidentally fall,\n" + "There'll be no green bottles hanging on the wall.";
    }
  }
  return lyrics;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `i` reaches 0 the line

```
var nextNumber = numbers[i - 1].charAt(0).toLowerCase() ...
```

will be problematic

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `.charAt()` error pops up on the final iteration of the loop. At this point, `i = 0`, so `numbers[i -1]` is trying to access an item at position -1 of the array. This obviously does not exist, so javascript considers it "undefined", thus the `.charAt()` fails.

Also, your test (at line 18): `i < 9`, results in the lyrics *starting* with what is traditionally held as the last lines of the song in the case where the function parameter `n >= 10`, and in any other case it will be omitted entirely.

Finally, your function will fail miserably if anyone enters a value greater than 10 for the function parameter n.

Suggestions: Change the for loop as follows. The test to differentiate with the running lines and the final line is changed to test for numbers positions greater than 0 (the final number is at position 0), and the text building stuff is moved to within the control statement to ensure that they are not run while processing the final numbers position.

```
for (i = n - 1; i > -1; i--) 
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        // since i > 0, [i - 1] will always be >= 0.
        var numberLine = numbers[i] + " green bottles hanging on the wall,\n";
        var nextNumber = numbers[i - 1].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + numbers[i - 1].slice(1, numbers[i - 1].length);

        lyrics = lyrics + numberLine + numberLine + "And if one green bottle should accidentally fall,\n" + "There'll be " + nextNumber + " green bottles hanging on the wall.\n";

     }
     else
     {

         // We only want this when i == 0, but from the limitation 
         // set on the for loop (i.e. i > -1)we can assume that 
         // i will never be < 0.

         lyrics = lyrics + 
             "One green bottle hanging on the wall,\n" + 
             "One green bottle hanging on the wall,\n" + 
             "If that one green bottle should accidentally fall,\n" + 
             "There'll be no green bottles hanging on the wall.";
     }
}
```

-S